# How to get and validate application/json data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I send data from client to server in `application/json` content type.

Then I try to take this information in server side like as:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{

        $data = $request->json()->all();
        var_dump($data); die();
}
```

It returns me empty `array()`

Also I tried to validate incoming POST using this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->json()->all(), []);
```

How to get and validate application/json data in Laravel?

I get POST data like as:

```
dd($_POST);

array:1 [▼
  "application/json" => "{"id":6,"unique_code":null,"name":"О","secondname":"П","lastname":"Валерьевич","datebirth":"14/10/1991 00:00:00","taxcode":"4545","gender":"1","created_at":null,"file":"C:\\db\\tests\\22-07-2017\\MMM1.TXT","orders":{"profession":"Директор","pacient_id":null,"payment":"1","kind_work":"1,2","factory_name":"FALKO","factory_edrpou":"2020","factory_departament":"IT","status_pass":"1","office_address":"Kiev","unique_code":"0","enterprise_id":"12","status":null},"http_code":null}"
]
```

Comment: Have you checked request has json data or not ? 
Can you check what is in `$request->all()`

Comment: `$request->all()` will give u the request payload whether its json or normal, but to check if its a json request or not , use `if ($request->expectsJson()) {...}` then use `return response()->json([key=>value])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an api I post json to. I have an api end point where I post this json

`{
  "email":"youremail@triumworks.com",
  "phone": "phone",
  "name": "name",
  "password": "password"
}`

The corresponding controller that handles the request looks like

```
public function create_account(Request $request){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $response = new Responseobject;     
    $array_data = (array)$data;

    $validator = Validator::make($array_data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'phone' => 'required|string|min:12|max:12|unique:users',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        $response->status = $response::status_failed;
        $response->code = $response::code_failed;
        foreach ($validator->errors()->getMessages() as $item) {
            array_push($response->messages, $item);
        }   
    }
    else{
        $api_token = str_random(60);
        $user = new User();
        $user->api_token = $api_token;
        $user->name = $data->name;
        $user->email = $data->email;
        $user->phone = $data->phone;
        $user->password = bcrypt($data->password);

        if($user->save()){
            $response->status = $response::status_ok;
            $response->code = $response::code_ok;
            $response->result = $user;
        }           
    }
    return Response::json(
            $response
        );
}
```

This does the same thing as the one above.

```
public function create_account(Request $request){
        $response = new Responseobject();

        $validator = Validator::make($request->json()->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'phone' => 'required|string|min:12|max:12|unique:users',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            $response->status = $response::status_failed;
            $response->code = $response::code_failed;
            foreach ($validator->errors()->getMessages() as $item) {
                array_push($response->messages, $item);
            }   
        }
        else{
            $api_token = str_random(60);
            $user = new User();
            $user->api_token = $api_token;
            $user->name = $data->name;
            $user->email = $data->email;
            $user->phone = $data->phone;
            $user->password = bcrypt($data->password);

            if($user->save()){
                $response->status = $response::status_ok;
                $response->code = $response::code_ok;
                $response->result = $user;
            }           
        }
        return Response::json(
                $response
            );
    }
```

Comment: How to validate this using Laravel?

Comment: What is `new Responseobject;`?

Comment: A class I defined to give a general format to my responses. Looks like this
    `<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

class Responseobject {
 const status_ok = "OK";
 const status_failed = "FAILED";
 const code_ok = 200;
 const code_failed = 400;
 const code_unauthorized = 403;
 const code_not_found = 404;
 const code_error = 500;
 public $status;
 public $code;
 public $messages = array();
 public $result = array();
}`

Comment: It gives me null: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        //$response = new Responseobject;
        $array_data = (array)$data;`

Comment: @OPV can you edit your question to include the whole function and if possible the whole class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149898/discussion-between-opv-and-the-sammie).

Answer (score 3):

The posted data will end up in the request body parameter bag. You get the data either via `$request->all()` or `$request->request->all()`.

So the Validator looks like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), []);
```

**Dive deeper:**

Or you can use the `validate()` method in your controllers. Which look like this:

```
$this->validate($request->all(), []);
```

Read more about this in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation).

To make things even more complicator, you don't even need to inject the Request instance to your controller. You can use the `request()` helper function. The register method then looks like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->validate(request()->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Nom it does not work, because I have POST in json format

Comment: When I use `Content-Type: application/json` and post data the my API (build with Laravel) the example above works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @OPV `$this->validate` automatically check it request is json or not and respond accordingly, u can check the method ur self

Comment: Do you mean use this? `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), []`?

Comment: Can you reformat your answer, I can not understans where is right solution

Comment: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given, called in ` when I try to use `request()`

Comment: I added a section `Dive deeper`. Everything above the `Dive deeper` section is the most easy solution for you.

Comment: See my `dd($_POST);` in question

Comment: The error is created because you're sending an instance of Request instead of an array. Which was my fault, I forgot to add `->all()` after the `request()`. If you copy the code above now it should work.

Comment: I use this: `$validator = Validator::make(request(), []`

Comment: You should use this: `$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), []);`

Comment: This works perfectly fine as long as you set your Content-Type to application/json in your request.